# Connection reset by peer: socket write error in java for file transfer program

Tags: java, sockets, websocket

I am trying to send 2000 files from 1 location to other in a same server using server socket programming java,
 I am using 10 threads to do that program works fine if

1. at night times when load is less
2. less files are given as input

it gives error for 2000 files as Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Comment: What errors show up at the other end? And what do you mean by 'same server'?

Answer (score 1):

The server is closing the socket, probably due to an overhead (too much connections or something).

You should post this to SuperUser or ServerFault, to learn how to increment the treeshold you are hitting, whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on any Unix, check the file descriptor limit with [`ulimit -n`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ulimit/). Chances are it's 1024 or something like that.